# How do I use javascript and google maps api to auto search "Pubs near me" using my GPS as a relative point of location in my website?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps, gps

I'm having the problem below,
Using javascript and google maps api to auto search "Pubs near me" using my GPS as a relative point of location in my website.
For example I load my website in progress which has google maps embedded into it, without a search function, to auto pinpoint my GPS location (Which I've done).
The trouble lies in auto-searching "Pubs near me" without a search box, to do it automatically for anyone viewing the website as it loads.
Here's the coding so far:

```
    <div id="mapholder">

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?output=embed&sensor=true"></script>

</div>

<script>
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);

function showPosition(position) {
    var searched = "pubs near me";

    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
    mapholder = document.getElementById('mapholder')
    mapholder.style.height = '550px';
    mapholder.style.width = '1000px';

    var myOptions = {
    center:latlon,zoom:15,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl:false,
    navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!"});
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: you've assigned `var searched = "pubs near me"` but you never do anything with it.

Comment: I ran your code and it says "Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys". Have you used google api key with the maps script ?

Comment: Hey Abdul, I'm using a logic that doesn't need an Api key that's why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Places JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#overview) library, it enable your application to search for places (defined in this API as establishments, geographic locations, or prominent points of interest) contained within a defined area, such as the bounds of a map, or around a fixed point.

With the Places service you can perform four kinds of searches:

```
- Nearby Search
- Text Search
- Radar Search
- Place Details Request
```

A Nearby Search lets you search for places within a specified area. You can refine your search request by supplying keywords or specifying the type of place you are searching for.

It restricts the results to places matching the specified type. Only one type may be specified (if more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored). See the list of [supported types.](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)